# ISML PAC to XForm Conversion

Tags: xforms

Are there any tools or write-ups that can help in converting ISML PACs to XForms? Does anyone have experience in such a conversion?

Comment: Could you tell us more about what ISML is?

Answer (score 0):

If ISML is an XML language, then you could use XSL transformation to generate XForms. I have done this with WSDL and XML Schema files, see http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2xforms/. Take a look at the source code, maybe you can make use some of the techniques used there.